# reference collapsing and and tuples

Tags: c++, reference, perfect-forwarding, stdtuple, reference-collapsing

I'm trying to convert a parameter pack into references, because some arguments to my function can be a mix of r-/l- values.
The function in question:

```cpp
//must return tuple
template <typename ...U>
std::tuple<U...> input(const char* format, U ...args) {
    std::tuple<U...> t = std::tuple<U...> (args...);
    //other code....
}
```

There is some test code that I can't touch...
This will call my function:

```cpp
template <typename... U>
std::tuple<U...> test_input(const char* fmt, U &&...inp) {
    input(fmt, std::forward<U>(params)...);
    //other stuff...
}
```

And 2 test objects (also untouchable) which have deleted copy/move constructors `A()` and `B()`. as in:

```cpp
A(const A &) = delete;            //same for B
A &operator=(const A &) = delete; //same for B
```

If I call the function, as is, I'll get "deleted copy-constructor" or "deleted constructor" errors. For example:

```cpp
test_input("blah blah", 1, i, "a", std::string("a"), A(123) B("string"));
```

The problem is that it can be any mix of r-/l-values and I don't know how to convert them to all be references

I understand that I need a reference to the arguments. I've tried using `std::forward`, `std::forward_as_tuple`, `std::make_tuple`, as well as changing the second parameter to `input` to be  `U & ...args` and `U &&...args`

I also understand that I need to use reference collapsing:

- A& & becomes A&
- A& && becomes A&
- A&& & becomes A&
- A&& && becomes A&&

I tried to use the first and third rules to convert anything to a type of `A&`, but I still get errors such as: `call to deleted constructor of 'B'` and `expects an l-value for 2nd argument`

In case my question wasn't clear - How do I convert `args`, the second argument of `input`, to a tuple of references?

Comment: Why doesn't your `input` method take `U&&...` as params only `U...`? Also have you considered using `std::forward_as_tuple` in your `input` method?

Comment: @W.F. with `U&&...`, I get `call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of std::tuple<B> `
with `std::forward_as_tuple`, I get `no viable conversion from tuple<B &&> to tuple<B>`
when I run `test_input("blah", B("string"));` for both examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

//must return tuple
template <typename ...U>
std::tuple<U&&...> input(const char*, U&&...args) {
    return std::tuple<U&&...>(std::forward<U>(args)...);
    //other code....
}

template <typename... U>
std::tuple<U&&...> test_input(const char* fmt, U &&...inp) {
    return input(fmt, std::forward<U>(inp)...);
    //other stuff...
}

struct A {
    A(int) { }
    A(const A &) = delete;            //same for B
    A &operator=(const A &) = delete; //same for B
};

struct B {
    B(const char *) { }
    B(const B &) = delete;            //same for B
    B &operator=(const B &) = delete; //same for B
};

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    test_input("blah blah", 1, i, "a", std::string("a"), A(123), B("string"));
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JGzRtEyuqoJjV7IU)

Comment: Thank you so much! It was my declaration of `std::tuple<U&&...>`. I was trying to debug the value being assigned to `std::tuple <U ...>`, and didn't think to check the type of the tuple!